# Smoothbars overlapping in Warsaw

Tags: beamer, overlap, headline

While using the theme Warsaw in beamer and `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}`, I get an annoying overlapping between the title of the frame and the lower part of the headline

[image]

My code is basically

```
\documentclass[cosmer,green,compress,9pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
 % Stuff
\end{document}
```

Any idea on where's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by changing the shading extent. I have copied the shading commands from `beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty` and modified it to reduce the overlap. The changes are marked.

```tex
\documentclass[cosmer,green,compress,9pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    % copied from beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection
    \else
        % option "subsection" is set to false
        {
            \usebeamerfont*{headline} % to set length of "ex" unit correctly
            \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
                color(0ex)=(frametitle.bg);%
                %color(1ex)=(frametitle.bg);%           % original
                %color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)   % original
                color(1ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)    % modified
            }
        }
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{s1}
    \frame{\frametitle{title}content}
    \subsection{ss1}
    \frame{\frametitle{title}content}
    \section{s2}
    \frame{\frametitle{title}content}
    \subsection{ss2}
    \frame{\frametitle{title}content}
    \frame{\frametitle{title}content}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]